# Cannot run Steam; missing libc.so.6

Tags: steam, dependencies

Like the title says, I have problems starting Steam.

Dishes out error; You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libc.so.6

Intel i5-6600k , 64-bit system, 16GB Ram, Nvidia 1070 (470 driver) - Running Elementary 6 Odin

**What I've tried, with no success;**

```
sudo apt install libc6-i386
```

**Tried running flatpak update, shows me this error;**

> ~$ flatpak update
>
> ```
> 1. [✗] org.freedesktop.Platform.Compat.i386 20.08  i  flathub 1.0 kB / 152.6 MB
> ```
>
> Warning: While trying to checkout c112a40c3697c2c12149f1041ca32da1cca7e309ff3dfb709b94fbde77beca08
>
> into
>
> /.local/share/flatpak/runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform.Compat.i386/x86_64/20.08/.c112a40c3697c2c12149f1041ca32da1cca7e309ff3dfb709b94fbde77beca08-0FRZ80:
>
> Opening content object
> da544d3558d79dd2f8e90178c902232d4879d603d2f51484aa66f4bf5e9e6678:
>
> Couldn't find file object
> 'da544d3558d79dd2f8e90178c902232d4879d603d2f51484aa66f4bf5e9e6678'
>
> Installation complete.

**Running flatpak uninstall unused produces;**

> ~$ flatpak uninstall --unused
>
> These runtimes in installation 'system' are pinned and won't be
> removed; see flatpak-pin(1):
> runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default/x86_64/20.08
>
> These runtimes in installation 'user' are pinned and won't be removed;
> see flatpak-pin(1):
> runtime/com.valvesoftware.Steam.CompatibilityTool.Proton/x86_64/stable
>
> Nothing unused to uninstall

**Trying to locate libc.so.6 produces;**

> ~$ locate libc.so.6
>
> /.local/share/flatpak/runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/20.08/63c4b310325615c74b8b5b2576733e3e7b751026cb5bf458c98ffacd7bfc6235/files/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
>
> /.local/share/flatpak/runtime/org.kde.Platform/x86_64/5.15/a0d4fa5ab86c591aeb9359410f75a86125a1b6114cc3bb453c487f85c7ccd83a/files/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
>
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
>
> /var/lib/flatpak/runtime/io.elementary.Platform/x86_64/6/f6458cfe79a53d649c33716c75262c1a2027121f0290b529644adee9a809d39e/files/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

**Running apt search libc6-i386 produces this result;**

> ~$ apt search libc6-i386
>
> Sorting... Done
>
> Full Text Search... Done
>
> libc6-i386/focal-updates,now 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 amd64 [installed]   GNU C
> Library: 32-bit shared libraries for AMD64
>
> libc6-i386-amd64-cross/focal-updates 2.31-0ubuntu9.2cross1 all   GNU C
> Library: 32-bit shared libraries for AMD64 (for cross-compiling)
>
> libc6-i386-cross/focal-updates 2.31-0ubuntu9.2cross1 all   GNU C
> Library: Shared libraries (for cross-compiling)
>
> libc6-i386-x32-cross/focal 2.31-0ubuntu7cross1 all   GNU C Library:
> 32-bit shared libraries for AMD64 (for cross-compiling)

//

Ran

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```

Did not fix the issue.

Uninstalled Steam flatpak and installed the .deb from Steam.

Updater starts and finishes.

**New error occurs;**

> ~$ steam
> Package xterm needs to be installed
>
> Running Steam on elementary 6 64-bit
>
> STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
>
> Steam runtime environment up-to-date!
>
> Steam client's requirements are satisfied
>
> WARNING: Using default/fallback debugger launch
>
> /.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam
>
> [2021-08-25 10:05:39] Startup - updater built Jul 20 2021 22:25:51
>
> Installing breakpad exception handler for
> appid(steam)/version(1626824053)
>
> libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
>
> libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
>
> SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
>
> X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range
> for operation)
>
> Major opcode of failed request:  151 (GLX)
>
> Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
>
> Value in failed request:  0x0
>
> Serial number of failed request:  44
>
> xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
>
> Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update
> check
>
> [2021-08-25 10:05:39] Loading cached metrics from disk
> (/.local/share/Steam/package/steam_client_metrics.bin)
>
> [2021-08-25 10:05:39] Failed to load cached hosts file (File
> 'update_hosts_cached.vdf' not found), using defaults
>
> [2021-08-25 10:05:39] Using the following download hosts for Public,
> Realm steamglobal
>
> [2021-08-25 10:05:39] 1. http://media.steampowered.com, /client/,
> Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 1, source = 'baked in'
>
> Installing breakpad exception handler for
> appid(steam)/version(1626824053)
>
> [2021-08-25 10:05:39] Checking for update on startup
>
> [2021-08-25 10:05:39] Checking for available updates...
>
> [2021-08-25 10:05:39] Downloading manifest:
>
> http://media.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12 Installing
> breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1626824053)
>
> [2021-08-25 10:05:40] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12
> version 1626824053, installed version 1626824053, existing pending
> version 0
>
> [2021-08-25 10:05:40] Nothing to do
>
> [2021-08-25 10:05:40] Verifying installation...
>
> [2021-08-25 10:05:40] Performing checksum verification of executable
> files
>
> [2021-08-25 10:05:40] Verification complete
>
> Loaded SDL version 2.0.15-6655637
>
> Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail"
>
> Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
>
> libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
>
> libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
>
> Steam: An X Error occurred
>
> X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
>
> Major opcode of failed request:  151
>
> Serial number of failed request:  50
>
> xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
>
> assert_20210825100539_1.dmp[16124]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
>
> /tmp/dumps/assert_20210825100539_1.dmp
>
> /.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 772: 16089 Segmentation fault
> $STEAM_DEBUGGER $DEBUGGER_ARGS "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"

Running

```
sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-(your driver version here):i386
    
sudo apt-get install libatk-adaptor:i386 libgail-common:i386
    
sudo reboot
```

Problem was fixed. Can run steam now.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your work. I wouldn't have figured it out without it.

I am running Elementary 6 Odin on the following system: Intel  i7-7700K , 64-bit system, 16GB Ram, Nvidia GTX 1060 6GB (470 driver)

My only suggestion is that the process can be simplified, and it is what worked for me a the time of writing, to the following commands:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
sudo apt install steam libatk-adaptor:i386 libgail-common:i386
sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-(your driver version here):i386
```

---

Note for all with this problem: It is possible to install Steam through Flathub, yet due to restrictions of Flatpak (mainly File System access) it is better to install the package through APT, which requires some extra steps, in this case is allowing the installation of x86 architecture packages and installation of missing dependencies.

Extra note: if you are running Open Source Drivers (MESA), you shouldn't install the libnvidia, instead install the following packages ([information taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40092796/libgl-error-failed-to-load-driver-swrast-running-ubuntu-docker-container-on)):

```
sudo apt install mesa-utils libgl1-mesa-glx
```